# Meltdown and Virtual Machines

Tags: virtualization, meltdown

> This question originated from a discussion [about VMs not being vulnerable](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/176645/149193) to Meltdown.

Can Meltdown "break out" of a virtual machine, so to speak?

What is meant by this is: Can a program (with any access and priveledge level desired) within a fully-virtualized machine use the [meltdown](/questions/tagged/meltdown) vulnerability to access memory on the host machine (which should include memory allocated to other VMs on the same host)?

Note that since [two](http://blog.cyberus-technology.de/posts/2018-01-03-meltdown.html) conflicting [references](https://www.vmware.com/us/security/advisories/VMSA-2018-0002.html) have already been cited, answers must not only give references, but show how any opposing references are incorrect or not giving the whole picture.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The references you mention don't conflict with each other. The first one claims for **Meltdown** that *"Fully virtualized machines are not affected"*. The second one claims that the product is *"vulnerable to **Bounds Check Bypass and Branch Target Injection** issues"*. These issues are not the Meltdown but the Spectre vulnerability.

Or to summarize:

- [CVE-2017-5753](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-5753) - Bounds Check bypass (Spectre) - works cross VM
- [CVE-2017-5715](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-5715) - Branch Target Injection (Spectre) - works cross VM
- [CVE-2017-5754](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-5754) - Rogue Data Cache Load (Meltdown) - does not work cross VM